# Amplify cookies Auth with default Cloudfront dns does not work

Tags: angular, cookies, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

A colleague and I are racking our brains on this one, so hoping one of you clever folk could point out what we're doing wrong...

We have an angular app served from S3 with a CloudFront distribution in front working all fine.  We are using the AWS Amplify SDK to authenticate with cookies, using the following (as suggested from the Amplify docs):

```js
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: environment.cognito_region,
    userPoolId: environment.cognito_user_pool_id,
    userPoolWebClientId: environment.cognito_user_pool_web_client_id,
    cookieStorage: {
        domain: '.dev.<our domain>.net',
        secure: true
    },
  }
});
```

What we want to do is fire up multiple Cloudfront distributions pointing to other s3 sites for feature branch testing.  We do not want to create dns entries each time, so we are trying to get the same approach working by using the default cloudfront.net dns.  So we just did this:

```js
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: environment.cognito_region,
    userPoolId: environment.cognito_user_pool_id,
    userPoolWebClientId: environment.cognito_user_pool_web_client_id,
    cookieStorage: {
        domain: '.cloudfront.net',
        secure: true
    },
  }
});
```

We changed the cloudfront distribution for this approach to use the default SSL cert etc, with no alias.

[Cloudfront setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKxbo.png)

This does not work however, so I assume we're missing something fundamental here, like Cloudfront DNS entries just can't be used in this way?  Here's what we're seeing in the console:

[Chrome console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGETV.png)

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem, the issue is that you must use the entire domain that cloudfront generates for you.
[image: Cloudfront domain]

```html
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: environment.cognito_region,
    userPoolId: environment.cognito_user_pool_id,
    userPoolWebClientId: environment.cognito_user_pool_web_client_id,
    cookieStorage: {
        domain: '.xxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net',
        secure: true
    },
  }
});
```